# AspNet Core SignalR - dependency issues when running on mono

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, mono, signalr

I'm trying to use **SignalR** client with **Unity 2018.4 LTS**.
I followed the steps in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) guide to connect from .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Standard 2.0 class library to my ASP.NET Core 3.0 web server.

I tried two versions of SignalR client, the newest one (3.0) and the most popular one (1.1). On both of these versions I'm having dependency issues when building connection.

The program is crashing on this

```cs
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl("http://localhost:50580/servershub").Build();
```

with an exception

```
Could not load type of field 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.HttpConnectionOptions:<HttpMessageHandlerFactory>k__BackingField' (3) due to: 
Could not resolve type with token 0100004e (from typeref, class/assembly System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51) assembly:netstandard, 
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51 type:System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler member:(null) signature:<none>
```

Before the above exception I'm also getting weird warning, that may not be related to the issue, because it's thrown by the game plugins framework.

```
Could not find dependency: System.Net.Http, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

Does anyone have a working solution or an example running SignalR client on Unity?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/dotnetProfileSupport.html?_ga=2.161732028.1079658668.1572637905-1699549765.1572637905 doesn't exactly give you the warm and fuzzy.